# pandas remove the values from column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello I created the pandas dataframe from a file values, i getting some deficulties dataframe lookong like

my input data frame

```
  agr_1                agr_2

 0,0,0,4,5,6,8,0       0,3,4,3,0,0,0
 0,5,6,0,5,5,0         0,3,4,5,5,6
 0,4,5,4,,5            0,4,3,4,5
```

i want to remove zero values and want to take average of rest of integer values without consideration of zero how can i achive this through pandas

output

```
 agr_1    agr_2      
    5      3.3
    4      4.25
    4.5    4
```

Comment: is your data string or list of strings/numbers?

Comment: Could you explain the way you create the dataframe in the first place?

Comment: Integer values, its a  file, i am reading as df=pd.read_csv('file_name', sep="\t")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a subroutine doing conversion to floats and calculating average value:

```
def mysub(r):
    lst = [float(a) for a in r.split(',') if a != '0' and a != '']
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)     


df['agr_1'].apply(mysub)

0    5.75
1    5.25
2    4.50
Name: agr_1, dtype: float64

df['agr_2'].apply(mysub)

0    3.333333
1    4.600000
2    4.000000
Name: agr_2, dtype: float64
```

Or apply it to both columns:

```
df.applymap(mysub)

   agr_1     agr_2
0   5.75  3.333333
1   5.25  4.600000
2   4.50  4.000000
```

Comment: `df.applymap(mysub)`

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
df.agr_1.str.split(',',expand=True).apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').replace({0:np.nan}).mean(1)
0    5.75
1    5.25
2    4.50
dtype: float64
```

Or

```
df.agr_1.str.extractall(r'([1-9])').astype(float).mean(level=0,axis=0).iloc[:,0]

0  5.75
1  5.25
2  4.50
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing that came to mind.  No argument that this is better.

```
pd.to_numeric(df.stack().str.split(',').explode(), errors='coerce') \
  .where(lambda x: x.ne(0)).mean(level=[0, 1]).unstack()

   agr_1     agr_2
0   5.75  3.333333
1   5.25  4.600000
2   4.50  4.000000
```

Comment: how can specify the column names to above script i have one more file with some string column, just want specify column name do the rest thank you